# Ionic 2 deeplinking no react

Tags: android, ionic2, deep-linking, applinks

I run this command :

```
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=kargosha --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=kargosha.com
```

And after that I put

> assetlink.json

in server (**kargosha.com**)
You can check this file [Here](https://kargosha.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json) Or test it [Here](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator). Anyway, finally I write a simple code in Codepen for opening app and click on it from android phone (android 6.0.1) but I don't see anything.

**Config.xml** :

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="com.kargosha" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
        <name>name</name>
        <description>name App</description>
        <author email="test@yahoo.com" href="http://test.com/">test</author>
        <content src="index.html" />
        <access origin="*" />
        <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
        <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.8.103:8100" />
        <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.8.108:8100" />
        <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
        <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
        <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
        <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
        <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
        <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
        <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
        <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
        <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
        <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
        <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
        <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
        <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
        <platform name="android">
            <allow-intent href="market:*" />
            //Some icon & splash
        </platform>
        <platform name="ios">
            <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
            <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
            //Some icon & splash
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
    //Some other plugin
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-deeplinks" spec="^1.0.15">
        <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="kargosha" />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_SCHEME" value="https" />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_HOST" value="kargosha.com" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved very stupidly, just with these commands :

```
ionic cordova platform rm <platform>
ionic cordova platform add <platform>
```